# RSA Verification Javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to verify an RSA signature in Javascript but I can't seem to get it to work. I think I have to do something with my key and signatures but I am very confused.

[Here](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-Signature-class) is a link to this library

```
var publicKey = "MIIBIjBNBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoPNkJzHqbY/6mAjJwb4zUbOiOjvmg3b8fvydYdGXdv04r6vzgn/FD5NPJM7bojAxi6sZ8vV+fYVIQey6HnrLSsdU/QXhT3p22a+kB4ym8SbKsOy2fWqL950nZCPYW/DC9txHy+ceFuKMAarFWAMJRe+MaVIbDIAAi8tMNjZ204GkmqveyAeA6JppzthAuiX69H8Zb3Hbs49CHNwLnSpKz5HBTfcgWqHkar2HlEFccvWC++Kq47MIkEcKScS/oneDb/TiL5ClOas1gMxfwiVtkFI6zNxxJOJDSTlY66oHCVCfTruk2pQbtOtwJEGrOwq6B536QL/EkeEKMgiqlpZJbQIDAQAB";
var stringToVerify = "aaa";
var signature = "hXyRmdQOCiVBNgDdGtiWF/gJwIk0Hs+MZtfEU4sFMEu05xsBjR9uymOJ/8FwhKCB0p+Kc1jqtsZxQqtxC0Du2EYyvjs0j5bbU9ZugZw0+9VHqKm0UA23djmZ1MT6nXt2ZEUEsS0La9yrfEnig/swAku1fQorsxG5FK5GFRjaacNIF+O0GOr0cbzEvlaAof6T6JFMueIw/iZykivs8XohSlghdPzoNmVueY9JF1XbtHZayau17jGhFTbeNNxbDBanPo593eZdgi5aTZMYHbxHx87cfU1sE5cjSioPQLsG9cQwVaWrrZa9BnB8IhR8Rv0NdRXYNTcVhc+sVHJN/QghNQ==";

var KJUR = require("cloud/jsrsasign-4.7.0/npm/lib/jsrsasign.js"); 
var verifier = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({alg: "SHA1withRSA", prov: "cryptojs/jsrsa"}); 
    verifier.init(publicKey);
    verifier.updateString(stringToVerify); 
    console.log(verifier.verify(signature));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468958/how-can-i-get-a-certificate-to-verify-my-rsa-digital-signature-using-jsrsasign?rq=1

Comment: Normally I would close this kind of question as well, but that API seems very tricky and I think it is therefore a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base 64 decode both the public key and the signature. They key and signature should then be re-encoded as hexadecimals. Then you hopefully should be able to use [this method](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KEYUTIL.html#.getKey) to generate a public `RSAKey` object.

I'm saying hopefully, as the the API description is just horrible. Personally I would not recommend to use such an API.

Comment: I will give it a shot and report. I agree that the API is horrible, do you have any alternatives? I can't seem to find an easy one to implement.

Comment: Not really, you could try and use CryptoJS directly. If I'm not mistaken it doesn't parse encoded keys though. And Node.js has a crypt package too. Note that there are many issues with regards to using JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately the Crypto implementation of Parse.com Cloud Code does not support verification. The Parse.com implementation is not Node.js either although it has many similarities. What a pain. Thanks